# Assign a DIV ID if a Child DIV contains a certain CLASS and STYLE attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site using a CMS and I need to keep the actual page content and strip-out all header & footer code, however there are no DIV ID tags and I don't have access to the back end to add the IDs.

So my question is:
How can I append a DIV ID called 'content' to 'div style="display:inline;float:left;"'
if its child DIV contains 'class="myclass"' AND 'style.width="610px"' using javascript or jQuery?

Thank you!

This is my code today:

```
<div>
  <div style="display:inline;float:left;">
    <div class="myclass" style="clear:both;width:610px;display:inline;float:left;">Content A</div>
    <div class="myclass" style="clear:both;width:610px;display:inline;float:left;">Content B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I want to change it to:

```
<div>
  <div id="content" style="display:inline;float:left;">
    <div class="myclass" style="clear:both;width:610px;display:inline;float:left;">Content A</div>
    <div class="myclass" style="clear:both;width:610px;display:inline;float:left;">Content B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Comment: My question has been answered by c-link. I can now append an ID to a parent DIV tag where no ID exists. The parent is a container for all actual page content. I can now easily strip-out everything around the content like navigation so that the page can be displayed in an iframe of a different site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var div$ = $('[style="display:inline;float:left;"]');
var childDiv$ = $('[class="myclass"][style*="width:610px;"]')
if(div$.children(childDiv$).length){
   div$.attr('id','content');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that attributes are used for styling, search with that attributes.

Otherwise you need to select by class name and filter out unwanted. Keep in mind that a `float`'ed element cannot be `display: inline;`, it's always `display: block;`.

```
$(function(){
  $(".myclass").each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var parent = that.parent();
    if(that.css("width") === "610px" && parent.css("display") == "block" && parent.css("float") == "left") {
        parent.attr("id", "content");
    }
  });  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've tried this example and had no success. I've also tried a few variations with no luck. However my question was solved in the example supplied by @c-link . Thank you very much for your time, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem. Attached is a fiddle with your example HTML and above code, working: http://jsfiddle.net/38qPn/